# MongoDB Authentication failed despite correct credentials

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose

I've ran into a strange issue today. I can't seem to connect to my local MongoDB container from my Node.js backend for local testing.

This is how I create my container:

```
docker start mongo || docker run --rm --name mongo -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=\"$MONGODB_USER\" -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=\"$MONGODB_PASSWORD\" -e MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=\"concept_slide\" -p 27017:27017 -d mongo:latest
```

I know for a fact that my app and database use the same credentials as they pull from the same environment variables:

```js
export const connectMongoDB = () => {
  console.log({
    user: process.env.MONGODB_USER,
    pass: process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD,
  });
  mongoose.connect(`mongodb://${process.env.MONGODB_TEST_HOSTNAME}:27017/concept_slide`, {
    user: process.env.MONGODB_USER,
    pass: process.env.MONGODB_PASSWORD,
    hostname: process.env.MONGODB_TEST_HOSTNAME,
  });

  mongoose.connection
    .on('connected', () => {
      console.log('Local database connected');
    })
    .on('error', (err) => {
      console.error(
        'Local database unreachable. Please check database or network access. Error: ',
        err
      );
    });
};
```

And here is the error message:

```
Local database unreachable. Please check database or network access. Error:  MongoServerError: Authentication failed.
    at Connection.onMessage (/Users/fareskissoum/Documents/Personal-Projects.tmp/open-concepts/open-concepts-backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:207:30)
    at MessageStream.<anonymous> (/Users/fareskissoum/Documents/Personal-Projects.tmp/open-concepts/open-concepts-backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:60:60)
    at MessageStream.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at processIncomingData (/Users/fareskissoum/Documents/Personal-Projects.tmp/open-concepts/open-concepts-backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:132:20)
    at MessageStream._write (/Users/fareskissoum/Documents/Personal-Projects.tmp/open-concepts/open-concepts-backend/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:33:9)
    at writeOrBuffer (node:internal/streams/writable:392:12)
    at _write (node:internal/streams/writable:333:10)
    at Writable.write (node:internal/streams/writable:337:10)
    at Socket.ondata (node:internal/streams/readable:766:22)
    at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:190:23) {
  ok: 0,
  code: 18,
  codeName: 'AuthenticationFailed',
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(1) { 'HandshakeError' }
```

I even tried to print them in the console to make sure whether there was an issue, and I confirm there aren't:

```
{ user: 'fares', pass: 'password', hostname: 'localhost' } // printed
```

[image: Credentials stored thru env vars in Docker container]

I don't understand where the issue comes from. I feel like I'm missing something.

Comment: What is the value of MONGODB_TEST_HOSTNAME? Are you trying to connect from another docker? Did you try connecting via Compass or another tool and compare results with the connection from your code?

Comment: Found the solution, adding answer

Answer (score 1):

I really need to stop coding this late.

It turns out the issue was that the database (`concept_slide`) didn't exist at the creation of the container/instance, hence there was nothing to connect to.

It's a mix of my ignorance and lack of clearer documentation.